# reading and processing lots of files with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, file-read

I need to read and process nearly 200 files every two hour. File sizes changes between 500KB - 10 MB.

What should be the best way of implementing that? Reading all that file is a I/O job. On the other hand i have to serialize the json in that file to a generic list which is a CPU job.

Do i need to seperate them with two different parallel jobs like first getting all files then processing them? Or get and process one after another in a parallel loop?

I also need the best storage type for them. I mean where to use concurrent bag or just list?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the simple and naive solution, read the files one by one, process them one by one? 200 * 10MB = 2GB, it doesn't sound like you need to do anything in particular to solve a performance issue here. In other words, do you **have** a performance issue, or do you **think** you have a performance issue?

Comment: For now, i do it in a for loop like get-process-repeat. It lasts 1 hour!. I think it has to be 10 min max

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give a more specific answer as this is tagged as C# and I am not very well versed in that language.

However, you could approach this from multiple avenues:

- Just do it one by one in a sequential fashion, as unless you're on a really slow CPU, disk, or have minimal memory constraints (which if you were, you would not be using C#!), then it will complete relatively quickly. Of course you can make things more difficult by doing the following two suggestions:
- If the application is more I/O bound, then you could use C#'s equivalent to BSD sockets C `select()` (ASync) statement, and then just use a single thread to parse and concatenate that data.
- Do as you suggested, open up multiple threads for each file, parse and serialise the contents of those files, then merge them into the main thread for later processing when all threads complete.